# REST API with two fields

Tags: rest, api, url, url-rewriting

I've read lot of API REST and the possible approaches but I'm not 100% clear about what I have to do.

I want to know what's the best way of do the following:

I have a secure REST with tokens related to accounts. Then I also have objects related to specific accounts.

I need to get objects depending on an accountId (this account is mandatory). The accountId is an attribute of the object.
An user can have more than one account so I need to send the accountId the user has selected to retrieve the specific objects.

Even if I search for a specific object I need to send the accountId (this account is related to security restrictions).

What is the best of doing that?

OPTION 1, as path parameter:

get all objects

```
/objects/account/{accountId}
```

get one object

```
/objects/{id}/account/{accountId}
```

OPTION 2:

get all objects

```
/objects?account=accountId
```

get one object

```
/objects/{id}?account=accountId
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

Although the account id is an attribute of the object, it sounds like the objects *belong* to the account. In that case I would recommend `/accounts/{id}/objects`. You could extend that to `/accounts/{id}/objects/{id}`, but I'm not sure you really need the account in the URL in order to find the object -- you should be able to use `/objects/{id}` and get the account from the auth token in headers to make sure the requester actually owns the object. Actually, you could do the same for `/objects`, if you don't mind that `/objects` returns a different list for different users.

For what it's worth, I don't think there is actually a "right" answer to this question. I've searched for answers to this question myself and there are good reasons to do it either way.

Comment: Great answer, the account is not part of the token, that's why it has to be sent as path/query param.

Comment: Ah I see. I missed the part where you said the user can have more than one account. If it is reasonable for a user to want to access all objects under all their accounts in one request, then your OPTION 2 makes the most sense for when they do want to filter by account. To me, OPTION 1 implies they are retrieving an account, not an object or list of objects.

Comment: The user has many accounts but he has to select one. The main idea is to search for just one account.. we will not search for all the accounts at the same time.